# sending multiple selected values comma-separated to a stored procedure

Tags: birt, actuate

I am currently using this:

```
params["RPBla"].join(",")
```

as default parameter of a (stored procedure) dataset. This works fine and sends one or more selected values from the report parameter RPBla to a stored procedure, e.g.:

```
1,2,3
```

Unfortunately, this does not work if the user does not select any value. Any ideas what to do. Actuate BIRT should send NULL instead of for example 1,2,3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about testing the content in this default value expression, something like:

```
if (params["RPBla"].value==null){
   null;
}else{
   var list=params["RPBla"].join(",");
   list.length>0 ? list : null;
}
```

Of course you could return anything you need instead of "null" here, for example returning a specific value warning the stored procedure that the filter should be disabled.

Comment: It doesn't help a lot. What is the expected behavior when nothing has been selected? Displaying all values, nothing or a specific default value? Which value is expected by this stored procedure when the selection is empty? As you mentionned "BIRT should send NULL" i believed null was taken into consideration in the stored procedure but it appears i misunderstood.

Comment: BIRT crashes it does not even issue a sql command (traced it)!